# redirect subfolder to subdomain excluding files .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have to redirect everything in a subfolder to the index of a subdomain.

At the moment I'm using RedirectMatch -

```
RedirectMatch 301 /subfolder http://subdomain.domain.com
```

But I need to still access the admin section of the subfolder, I've looked at various options and came up with the below but it doesn't work -

```
RewriteRule ^/subfolder$ http://subfolder.domain.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/subfolder/admin$ - [L]
```

Is this along the right lines or should it be something totally different?